# Программно задавать layout_gravity для custom view

Tags: android, customview

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь сделать кастомную вьюху.

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

private LinearLayout containerBackground;

private int type;

public static final int TYPE_IN = 0x00000000;
public static final int TYPE_OUT = 0x00000001;

public CustomView (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView (Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initAttrs(attrs);
}

public CustomView (Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initAttrs(attrs);
}

private void initAttrs(AttributeSet attrs){
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.widget, this);

    containerBackground = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_background);

    final TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView);
    if (typedArray != null) {

        setType(typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomView_type, 0x00000000));
        typedArray.recycle();
    }
}

public void setType (int type){
    this.type = type;
    if (type == TYPE_IN){
        containerBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in);
    } else if (type == TYPE_OUT){
        containerBackground.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out);
    } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type" + type);
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}}
```

В зависимости от параметра type хочу задавать layout_gravity RIGHT или LEFT в методе setType. Пробовал сделать следующим образом, но ничего не сработало.

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    setLayoutParams(params);
```

Как можно программно выставлять layout_gravity внутри кастомной вьюхи?

**UPD: Каким образом можно программно, внутри кода кастомной вьюхи, задавать ее расположение относительно ViewGroup в который она помещена?**

Answer (score 0):

Раз у вас потомок от `LinearLayout`, так и параметры соответсвующие надо использовать.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = ...
```

`FrameLayout.LayoutParams` из другой ветки, там другой `gravity`.

Comment: Я наверное немного некорректно задал вопрос. 
Каким образом можно программно задавать расположение кастомной вьюхи внутри ViewGroup?

Comment: С помощью подкласса `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, a он, как правило, у каждого потомка `ViewGroup` переопределен.

Comment: Другими словами, используйте подкласс `LayoutParams` контейнера.